# Java primitive types promotion confusion

Tags: java, numbers

I am new to this as you may be able to tell, please clarify to a beginner how the following code snipped outputs -2.50 as the answer. I'm still very confused around the promotion/demotion subject in terms of int -> double.

```
    int x = 5;
    double y = 2.5;
    double q = x / 10 - y;
    System.out.printf("%.2f\n",q);
```

The way I see it is: double q = 5.0 (x promoted to double from int) / 10.0 - 2.5
Which would be equal to 0.5 - 2.5 = -2.00 (2 decimal places because of "%.2f\n")

Why is the correct answer -2.50 and not -2.00?

Comment: Hint.. Division has higher priority than subtraction. Division happens first (and its value will be 0) then "2.5" is subtracted from 0.

Comment: @TheLostMind I understand that division comes before substraction but why would the value be 0 for the division

Comment: That's mentioned in the JLS. You first divide integers as integers and then convert if necessary

Comment: @TheLostMind Thanks a lot.

Comment: Read about widening primitive conversions [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html
visit this link to clear your confusion

Answer (score 4):

X is an integer and the value of x/10 would yield 0 and not 0.5( because x and 10 are both int). If you do x/10.0, then the output would be 0.5.

Comment: Makes sense, but in that case.. when does the promotion of the int to a double take place?

Comment: If the immediate operation involves an double. Meaning x/10.0d would convert x in double since 10.0d is double

Answer (score 2):

You could also write your expression like this:

`double q = (x / 10) - y;`

Now inside the parenthesis there are no doubles, so it's a pure `int`-division, which gives `5 / 10 = 0`. After that you have

`double q = 0 - y;`

Now you have a difference of an `int` with a `double`. And here is where the promotion from `(int)0` to `(double)0.0` takes place.

The final result will be

`double q = 0.0 - 2.5; //q == -2.5`

Answer (score 1):

`double q = x / 10 - y;`
In this since division has greater precedence than subtraction therefore `x/10` will execute first and here we are dividing two ints ( irrespective of the fact that the variable where final answer is stored is a double), so answer will be an integer i.e 5/10 = 0 and then subtraction of an int and double will be done (here int will be promoted to a double). So effectively it is 0.0 - 2.5 now, thus answer is -2.50

Answer (score 0):

```
double q = x / 10f - y;

x / 10 // it will be thought as int
```

Comment: when does the promotion of the int to a double take place?